# Creating a graph based on specific conditions

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a question that asks me to make a graph such that the BFS and DFS trees from the graph is not a minimum spanning tree and the order of the adjacency list does not matter, I know the properties of BFS DFS and MST but I'm a confused by the question. How should I be approaching the problem? (not looking for the solution)

Comment: Can you tell me exactly if you are asked later to run a shortest-path algorithm or anything else? However , you can't change the structure of the graph and it depends on the input values that a graph is tree or not!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a complete graph on `k` vertices. For `k > 3`, a `DFS` tree will always look different from a `BFS` tree. For `k > 4`, you can have a `MST` that is different from both the `BFS` and `DFS` trees. You can choose the shape of the `MST` to be different from the `DFS` tree by ensuring one vertex needs three edges coming out of it. You can choose the shape of the `MST` to be different from the `BFS` tree by ensuring no vertex has more than three edges coming out of it. You choose the shape of the `MST` by assigning weights to make the edges you choose, and only those edges, part of the `MST`.

```
DFS Tree

1-----2----3
           |
           |
     4-----5

BFS Tree

      1
  ____|____
 /   / \   \
2   3   4   5

MST

2
|
1---3---5
|
4
```

The complete graph on five vertices has 5 * 4 / 2 = 10 edges, of which only four are needed in any tree.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to look at an algorithm for finding the MST from a graph, and think about why it is not just a BFS or DFS search.

For any algorithm, finding an edge case that actually tests the tricky parts is an important part of implementation. You could start with a simple example, and try adding new edges or altering the input in a way that would make a simple BFS/DFS search fail.

The condition that it should be independent of the adjacency list order is to ensure that your test graph has a truly hard structure, not just that you have artificially fed the edges to the algorithm in a way that makes it fail.